# Unable to run {N} application with AOT, Reflect.getMetadata is not a function

Tags: webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Trying to make my nativescript application run with aot enabled.
Using the latest version of nativescript, and it builds just fine. When starting the application the error `Reflect.getMetadata is not a function` shows up and the application doesn't work.
This happens when using dependencies that rely on Reflect.getMetadata, for example: https://github.com/ghidoz/angular2-jsonapi

Demo project that errors when using aot:
https://github.com/annervisser/nativescript-aot-error

The application runs perfectly using JIT, and only breaks when using the `--env.aot` flag. Webpack is always enabled, since this is an angular project (always ran with the `--bundle` flag)

Full stacktrace:

```
System.err: TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function
System.err: File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     Frame: function:'saveAnnotations', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/vendor.js', line: 78279, column: 36
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/vendor.js', line: 78322, column: 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'module.exports../app/shared/models/user.model.ts.__decorate', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 2287, column: 110
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 2302, column: 5
System.err:     Frame: function:'./app/shared/models/user.model.ts', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 2348, column: 2
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 752, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'fn', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 122, column: 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'./app/shared/auth/auth.service.ts', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 1355, column: 76
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 752, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'fn', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 122, column: 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'./app/shared/auth/auth-interceptor.service.ts', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 1280, column: 71
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 752, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'fn', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 122, column: 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'./app/app.module.ngfactory.js', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 1041, column: 96
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 752, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'fn', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 122, column: 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 2387, column: 83
System.err:     Frame: function:'./main.ts', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 2465, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 752, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'checkDeferredModules', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 45, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 828, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/bundle.js', line: 831, column: 10
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/nl.persistence.stubs/files/app/starter.js', line: 2, column: 1
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err: 
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:624)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:616)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5871)
```

I've tried importing reflect-metadata in different places, including `polyfills.ts`, `main.tns.ts`, `app.module.tns.ts`
I've also tried including it in my webpack / tnsconfig and changing the target to be es2015 or es6.
None of these make any difference.

Searching for this error results in a lot of general information for angular, suggesting adding an import for `reflect-metadata` to `polyfills.ts`. This doesn't help.

Comment: Can you share the sample project where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @Manoj Added link to demo project: https://github.com/ghidoz/angular2-jsonapi

Comment: Apologies, wrong link. Demo project is here: https://github.com/annervisser/nativescript-aot-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the import statement for `reflect-metadata` package at top of your app module (basically before accessing `JsonApiDatastoreConfig` decorator.

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

Comment: This solved the issue, such a simple fix!
**Make sure to delete the `platforms/` folder** after adding this import, I forgot to do this which caused me to believe this didn't fix it. Thanks so much!